# flutter fire base fetch nested collections in tab bar tb bar view

Tags: flutter

how I can fetch nested collection 
{
  '1': {"name" : "category_1",
         "image" : "url"
        "items": {
           "0": "a", 
           "2": "c"
        }
       },
  '2': {"name" : "category_2",
        "image" : "url"
        "items": { 
           "2": "c", 
           "3": "d"
        }
       }
}
in tabbar tabbarview

Answer (score 0):

```
http.get(url).then((response) => {
  if(response.status == 200) {
    var data =  jsonDecode (response.body["someNestedCollecton"]);
    Print(data);
  }
}
```